# Не работает await Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise, lazyloading

Не ждет выполнения всех промисов, а просто после после функции this.load бежит в "третью" функцию, а картинки(загрузку которых я по идее пытаюсь дождаться) все еще продолжают загружаться. Объясните пож, что делаю не так?

Есть функция:

```
async lazyLoad(ind) {
  if (this.firstForLazy) {
    //этот await не не срабатывает.
    await Promise.all([...this.items[ind].querySelectorAll('.Glazy')].map(child => {
      return this.load(child, child.getAttribute('data-src'))
    }))
  }
}
```

Функция this.load:

```
load(el, url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    el.addEventListener('load', () => {
      el.classList.remove('Glazy')
      resolve()
    })
    el.src = url
  })
}
```

UPD:
В общем я решил добавить lazyLoad в свой слайдер и начал тестово это реализовывать и код пошел "лавиной", на хорошую архитектуру не претендую. первый вызов:

```
async createSlider() {
   this.buildMainElement()
   if (typeof this.finalSettings.lazyLoad === 'number') { 
       this.setLazyLoad() // - это нам не интересно 
       this.firstLazyLoad() 
    } 
    ...
}
```

firstLazyLoad:

```
async firstLazyLoad() { 
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        if(...){ 
            await this.lazyLoad(i) 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не понимаете как работает promise, перечитайте еще раз документацию, [тык](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/reference/Global_Objects/Promise) Разберитесь в какой момент вызывать resolve и reject, для чего и зачем.

Comment: Я сразу скажу спасибо, всем кто посоветует документацию. Я ее читал и нет да нет писал рабочий код на промисах, но не все еще понимаю. Ткните дурака носом, я только учусь

Comment: У вас `map` не возвращает ничего. А по идеи, должен возвращать Promise.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо! Неприятная заноза в виде забытого return'a устранена.
`return this.load(child, child.getAttribute('data-src'))`.
Но `Promis.all` все равно работает так же. С помощью `map` я хочу возвращать массив промисов, выполнение которых должен дождаться `Promise.all`

Comment: Значит, где-то есть еще ошибка. В приведенном коде больше нет ошибок. Кстати, поправьте код в вопросе. Как вы вызываете `lazyLoad`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko В общем я решил добавить lazyLoad в свой слайдер и начал тестово это реализовывать и код пошел "лавиной", на хорошую архитектуру не претендую.
первый вызов:
`if (typeof this.finalSettings.lazyLoad === 'number') {
      this.setLazyLoad() // - это нам не интересно
      this.firstLazyLoad()
}`

firstLazyLoad
`async firstLazyLoad() {
    if(...){
       await this.lazyLoad(i)
    }
}`

Comment: Вы лучше добавляйте код в вопрос.

Comment: Вы при вызове `this.firstLazyLoad()` не используете `await`. Соответственно, функция `createSlider` не дожидается выполнения `firstLazyLoad`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вот тут и есть один из моих пробелов в промисах. Дело в том, что мне нужно что бы я дождался загрузки только одной картинки из тех, что будут загружаться со страницей. Ну к примеру, на слайдере пользователь поставил 5 картинок(загрузить сразу), для корректной и быстрой работы, я хочу из этого стека дождаться только первой картинки, а остальные пусть загружаются параллельно. Т.е. что бы `createSlider` не ждал пока загрузяться все, а начал работать уже после загрузки первой картинки. и вот внутри `LazyLoad` я реализую логики, мол ты в первый раз жди `load`, а потом не жди.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Поэтому и не ставил `await` в `createSlider`, думая что ждать будет где то внутри `firstLazyLoad`. Так видимо нельзя?

Comment: Ну вот, у вас совсем другой вопрос, оказывается. Его и надо было задавать! Если вам нужно дождаться загрузки только первой картинки, то **не** делайте массив промисов. Сделайте ожидание загрузки только первой картинки.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ну этот вопрос родился в процессе решения первого)
И я наверно не совсем полно описал задачу, нужно что бы первый слайд из тех, что пользователь оставил на показ, сразу загрузился отдельно, а остальные пофиг кода. Но сам слайд не обязательно картинка, картинка может быть вложена внутрь "слайда"(тега, элемента), и может быть не одна. Вот я и говорю в этой части проверь детей и загрузи их всех. В общем я вроде во всем разобрался, где надо писать await. 
Огромное спасибо, что помог!

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код вполне рабочий. Может, у вас ошибка где-то в другом месте.

```js
async function lazyLoad() {
  //этот await не не срабатывает.
  console.log('before await')
  await Promise.all([...document.querySelectorAll('img')].map(child => {
    return load(child, child.getAttribute('data-src') + Math.round(Math.random() * 500))
  }));
  console.log('after await')
}

function load(el, url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    el.addEventListener('load', () => {
      el.classList.remove('Glazy')
      resolve()
      console.log('loaded image', url)
    })
    el.src = url
  })
}

(async function() {
  console.log('before lazyLoad')
  await lazyLoad();
  console.log('after lazyLoad')
})();
```

```html
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/">
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/">
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/">
```